# How to put a var instead of a string in Email Validation package

Tags: validation, email, flutter, var

I need to put a var in the string place in email validator:

```
var email;

void validation(){
bool emailvalidated = EmailValidator.validate(email);
if (emailvalidated) {
print('object');
}
}
```

but it throw me this error :
Invalid arguments: email.
Help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because the `validate` method needs a `string`.

Replace your code with the one below:
It works perfectly well:

```
// change your email variable to a have a default string
var email = 'youremail.com';

void validation(){
bool emailvalidated = EmailValidator.validate(email);
if (emailvalidated) {
print('object');
}
}
```

I hope it helps.

**UPDATED**

Add the variables below to your class:

```
 // define a controller to assign to your custom text field
  TextEditingController emailEditingController = TextEditingController();

 // declare the email variable here
  String email;
```

Replace your emailTextFormField widget with the one below:

```
 Widget emailTextFormField() {
    return CustomTextField(
      // assign your email controller to the custom text field here
      textEditingController: emailEditingController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      icon: Icons.email,
      hint: "Email ID",
      textEditingController: email,
    );
  }
```

Replace this with your validation function

```
 void validation() {
// email should be instantiated here
  email = emailEditingController.text;
    bool emailvalidated = EmailValidator.validate(email);
    if (emailvalidated) {
      print('Email validated');
    } else{
      print('email not validated');
     }
  }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I need to validate the email that the user enters in the CustomTextField, as email is the controller,

Comment: Okay. Do this: ```email = textEditingController.text;```. That would get the text in your textfield f you have a controller assigned to it

Comment: Instance member 'text' can't be accessed using static access.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_signup/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:login_signup/ui/widgets/custom_shape.dart';
import 'package:login_signup/ui/widgets/customappbar.dart';
import 'package:login_signup/ui/widgets/responsive_ui.dart';
import 'package:login_signup/ui/widgets/textformfield.dart';
import 'package:email_validator/email_validator.dart';

class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpScreenState createState() => _SignUpScreenState();
}

class _SignUpScreenState extends State<SignUpScreen> {
  bool checkBoxValue = false;
  double _height;
  double _width;
  double _pixelRatio;
  bool _large;
  bool _medium;
  var email;

  void validation(var val) {
    bool emailvalidated = EmailValidator.validate(val);
    if (emailvalidated) {
      print('object');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    _pixelRatio = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
    _large = ResponsiveWidget.isScreenLarge(_width, _pixelRatio);
    _medium = ResponsiveWidget.isScreenMedium(_width, _pixelRatio);

    return Material(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          height: _height,
          width: _width,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Opacity(opacity: 0.88, child: CustomAppBar()),
                clipShape(),
                form(),
                acceptTermsTextRow(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: _height / 35,
                ),
                button(),
                infoTextRow(),
                socialIconsRow(),
                //signInTextRow(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget clipShape() {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Opacity(
          opacity: 0.75,
          child: ClipPath(
            clipper: CustomShapeClipper(),
            child: Container(
              height: _large
                  ? _height / 8
                  : (_medium ? _height / 7 : _height / 6.5),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Colors.orange[200], Colors.pinkAccent],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Opacity(
          opacity: 0.5,
          child: ClipPath(
            clipper: CustomShapeClipper2(),
            child: Container(
              height: _large
                  ? _height / 12
                  : (_medium ? _height / 11 : _height / 10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Colors.orange[200], Colors.pinkAccent],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: _height / 5.5,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  spreadRadius: 0.0,
                  color: Colors.black26,
                  offset: Offset(1.0, 10.0),
                  blurRadius: 20.0),
            ],
            color: Colors.white,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
          child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print('Adding photo');
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add_a_photo,
                size: _large ? 40 : (_medium ? 33 : 31),
                color: Colors.orange[200],
              )),
        ),
//        Positioned(
//          top: _height/8,
//          left: _width/1.75,
//          child: Container(
//            alignment: Alignment.center,
//            height: _height/23,
//            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
//            decoration: BoxDecoration(
//              shape: BoxShape.circle,
//              color:  Colors.orange[100],
//            ),
//            child: GestureDetector(
//                onTap: (){
//                  print('Adding photo');
//                },
//                child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo, size: _large? 22: (_medium? 15: 13),)),
//          ),
//        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget form() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: _width / 12.0, right: _width / 12.0, top: _height / 20.0),
      child: Form(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            firstNameTextFormField(),
            SizedBox(height: _height / 60.0),
            lastNameTextFormField(),
            SizedBox(height: _height / 60.0),
            emailTextFormField(),
            SizedBox(height: _height / 60.0),
            phoneTextFormField(),
            SizedBox(height: _height / 60.0),
            passwordTextFormField(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget firstNameTextFormField() {
    return CustomTextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      icon: Icons.person,
      hint: "First Name",
    );
  }

  Widget lastNameTextFormField() {
    return CustomTextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      icon: Icons.person,
      hint: "Last Name",
    );
  }

  Widget emailTextFormField() {
    return CustomTextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      icon: Icons.email,
      hint: "Email ID",
      textEditingController: email,
    );
  }

  Widget phoneTextFormField() {
    return CustomTextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      icon: Icons.phone,
      hint: "Mobile Number",
    );
  }

  Widget passwordTextFormField() {
    return CustomTextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      obscureText: true,
      icon: Icons.lock,
      hint: "Password",
    );
  }

  Widget acceptTermsTextRow() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: _height / 100.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Checkbox(
              activeColor: Colors.orange[200],
              value: checkBoxValue,
              onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  checkBoxValue = newValue;
                });
              }),
          Text(
            "I accept all terms and conditions",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                fontSize: _large ? 12 : (_medium ? 11 : 10)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget button() {
    return RaisedButton(
      elevation: 0,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
      onPressed: () {
        validation(email);
      },
      textColor: Colors.white,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
//        height: _height / 20,
        width: _large ? _width / 4 : (_medium ? _width / 3.75 : _width / 3.5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: <Color>[Colors.orange[200], Colors.pinkAccent],
          ),
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Text(
          'SIGN UP',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: _large ? 14 : (_medium ? 12 : 10)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget infoTextRow() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: _height / 40.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "Or create using social media",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                fontSize: _large ? 12 : (_medium ? 11 : 10)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget socialIconsRow() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: _height / 80.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 15,
            backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/googlelogo.png"),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 15,
            backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/fblogo.jpg"),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 15,
            backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/twitterlogo.jpg"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget signInTextRow() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: _height / 20.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "Already have an account?",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(SIGN_IN);
              print("Routing to Sign up screen");
            },
            child: Text(
              "Sign in",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                  color: Colors.orange[200],
                  fontSize: 19),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You didn't add your ```CustomTextField``` code @Omar Yacop

Comment: I had:
Widget emailTextFormField() {
    return CustomTextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      icon: Icons.email,
      hint: "Email ID",
      textEditingController: email,
    );
  }

Comment: Can you add it to the code you just uploaded please? @Omar Yacop

Comment: What I am asking you to add to the upload is this file ```import 'package:login_signup/ui/widgets/textformfield.dart';``` @Omar Yacop. With that, I will be able to solve the error in your code.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize what you want

Comment: I had checked .

Comment: But you defined textEditingController twice. 
var email = emailEditingController.text Only static members can be accessed in initializers.dart(implicit_this_reference_in_initializer) The type of 'email' can't be inferred because it refers to an instance getter, 'emailEditingController', which has an implicit type. Add an explicit type for either 'email' or 'emailEditingController'

Comment: The last update works good but it says validated if it has letters, @,gmail.com but if it has ./;''[[][;. it is not validated. 
So I can work with this for now, but how can I sign up this on firebase and Thanks very much.

Comment: Ask that in another question. I will respond. This question looks disorganized already @Omar Yacop

Answer (score 0):

```
Here:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_signup/ui/widgets/responsive_ui.dart';

class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hint;
  final TextEditingController textEditingController;
  final TextInputType keyboardType;
  final bool obscureText;
  final IconData icon;
  double _width;
  double _pixelRatio;
  bool large;
  bool medium;


  CustomTextField(
    {this.hint,
      this.textEditingController,
      this.keyboardType,
      this.icon,
      this.obscureText= false,
     });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    _pixelRatio = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
    large =  ResponsiveWidget.isScreenLarge(_width, _pixelRatio);
    medium=  ResponsiveWidget.isScreenMedium(_width, _pixelRatio);
    return Material(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      elevation: large? 12 : (medium? 10 : 8),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: textEditingController,
        keyboardType: keyboardType,
        cursorColor: Colors.orange[200],
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(icon, color: Colors.orange[200], size: 20),
          hintText: hint,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
              borderSide: BorderSide.none),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you advise me with a better way to validate the email??

Comment: There is this Google sign-in package but I always have errors
https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in

Comment: Updated, check now. If it doesn't work. I'll give a better way to validate email.

Comment: I have added static in front of TextEditingcontroller and it solved it but it gave me this textEditingController: email=> The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TextEditingController'.

Comment: I gave up, what is the better way, please.

Comment: Can I add this method :
'String validateEmail(String value) {
    String pattern =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (value.length == 0) {
      return "Email is Required";
    } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
      return "Invalid Email";
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }'

Comment: That was the better option I wanted to give. I found what was wrong with the code. Check the updated one. Works perfectly.

Comment: Just copy the last three codes section and everything would be fine